# add click listener to entire appwidget

Tags: android, layout, click, listener, android-appwidget

I have an appwidget and I want to add a click listener on the entire appwidget layout, not only on TextView ecc.
This is not working

```
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.layout.profile_widget_layout, pendingIntent);
```

How can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `setOnClickPendingIntent()` with a layout resource ID, only with a widget ID.

All you need to do is assign an `android:id` attribute to your outermost container (e.g., `RelativeLayout`), then use `setOnClickPendingIntent()` with that `android:id` value.

Answer (score 0):

This may no longer be *quite* true, as I've spent the last few days scratching my head about why it did **not** work for me when I was trying to set the intent on the master RelativeLayout (R.id.TheEntireWidget) for my widget.  (Yes, the clickable attribute was set to true.)

The moment I started applying this to **visible drawables**, functionality!

I suspect this may have been changed to deal with a transparent something-or-otehr possibly intercepting touches.  My widget has no background or anything otherwise visible assigned to the top-level RelativeLayout.